# How to find the level of a specific Node

Tags: xml, xslt, xmlnode

My XML:

```
<menu>
  <item id=1>
    <item id=1.1>
      <item id=1.1.1>
        <item id=1.1.1.1>
        <item id=1.1.1.2>
        <item id=1.1.1.3>
      </item>
    </item>
    <item id=1.2>
      <item id=1.2.1>
        <item id=1.2.1.1>
        <item id=1.2.1.2>
        <item id=1.2.1.3>
      </item>
    </item>
  </item>
</menu>
```

And my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="menuId"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:if test="descendant-or-self::*[@id=$menuId]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:if test="descendant-or-self::*[@id=$menuId] | 
                                parent::*[@id=$menuId] | 
                                preceding-sibling::*[@id=$menuId] | 
                                following-sibling::*[@id=$menuId] |
                                preceding-sibling::*/child::*[@id=$menuId] | 
                                following-sibling::*/child::*[@id=$menuId]">
    <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm applying some rules to get just a specific node. That's ok. But now I need to get just X (this number can vary) levels above from the selected menuId

For example. If the X level number is 2 and the menuId is 1.1.2.3 the result would be:

```
<menu>
    <item id=1.1>
      <item id=1.1.1>
        <item id=1.1.1.1>
        <item id=1.1.1.2>
        <item id=1.1.1.3>
      </item>
    </item>
    <item id=1.2>
    </item>
</menu>
```

If the X level number is 1, the result would be:

```
<menu>
      <item id=1.1.1>
        <item id=1.1.1.1>
        <item id=1.1.1.2>
        <item id=1.1.1.3>
      </item>
</menu>
```

To get the current level I would use `count(ancestor::*)`. But I don't know how to get the node[@id = $menuId] level. 
I need to include something like `count(ancestor::*) >= (count(ancestor::node[@id = $menuId]) - X)` inside my IF

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient way I can think to approach this would be to pass a counting parameter down the `apply-templates` chain:

```
<xsl:variable name="targetDepth" select="count(//item[@id=$menuId]/ancestor::item)" />
<!-- I haven't thought this through in great detail, it might need a +1 -->

<xsl:template match="item">
  <xsl:param name="depth" select="0" />
  ....
  <xsl:if test=".... and ($targetDepth - $depth) &lt;= $numLevels">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="item">
        <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="$depth + 1" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ian. What was missing for me was this targetDepth. It's exactly what I need. Sorry but I can't vote up. :)

Comment: @Adriano note that for this to work the item ids _must_ be unique - if there are two different `item` elements with the same ID then `targetDepth` would end up being the _sum_ of their respective depths.

Comment: I know that. I'm totally aware about this and already told to my team that it must be unique. Thanks.